# Android socket io client node js cant get values

Tags: java, android, node.js, object, socket.io

I am developing an android application implementing socket io client by using https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client.

My Nodejs server

```
var app = require('http').createServer(),    
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    http = require('http'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    connectionsArray = [],
    connection = mysql.createConnection({               
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'login',
        port: 3306
    });

app.listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { 
    socket.on('register_usernames', function (data) {
        io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('register_usernames' , {username:"one"});
        io.sockets.socket.(socket.id).emit('register_usernames_one', {username:"two"});
        getBookingHistory(data);
    });

    connectionsArray.push(socket);
});
```

Android Client

```
package com.nuappz.socketdemo;

import io.socket.IOAcknowledge;
import io.socket.IOCallback;
import io.socket.SocketIO;
import io.socket.SocketIOException;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class Search extends Activity implements IOCallback{
    SocketIO socket;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            // Try making the socket connection
            socket = new SocketIO("http://nuappzdev.weteksi.com:3000/");
            socket.connect(this);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        socket.emit("register_usernames", "123");   
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
    @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(event.equals("register_usernames")) {
            Log.d("message response", args.toString());
        } else if (event.equals("register_usernames_one")) {
            Log.d("message reply", args.toString());
        }   
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

In on Method when the event recevied it displays the args. But it shows the following error

Logcat

```
06-09 18:25:52.321:I/io.socket(1890):>5:::{"args":       ["123"],"name":"register_usernames"}
06-09 18:25:52.322: I/io.socket(1890): < 1::
06-09 18:25:52.408: I/io.socket(1890): < 5:::{"name":"message_response","args":  [{"username":"one"}]}
06-09 18:25:52.409: D/message response(1890): [Ljava.lang.Object;@4177d208
06-09 18:25:52.409: I/io.socket(1890): < 5:::{"name":"message_reply","args": [{"username":"two"}]}
06-09 18:25:52.409: D/message reply(1890): [Ljava.lang.Object;@41739f30
06-09 18:25:52.471: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=16: interp stack at 0x5d914000
```

1.How can i send data on emit and how to get it from the client side.
2.How can i send an array or Json and parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found what is the real problem was.
As i have tried getting values in object which holding the array.
The object itself an array. So

How i tried is:

```
args.toString();
```

The object cant be converted to a string.

I achieved by this:

```
args[0].toString(); //args[position].toString();
```

Thus how i have cleared my problem..